# Creating a post with picture

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'd like to add a feature of adding a post to my blog-app that is built using React+Redux. Basically, I want a new post to consist of author's name, his text and a picture that you can attach to the post that you're going to create. I tried using input tag with type="file", but it returns a value with encrypted adress. How do I go about getting a picture from someone's device?

Comment: Use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-imageloader

Comment: thanks,that's what I needed